# Json loads error parsing

Tags: python, json, django, python-3.x, django-views

I'm coding in Django python and I want to decode a json string. In my view I'm doing the following :

```
body = json.loads(request.body)
```

Sometimes I'm getting the following error :

```
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Invalid \uXXXX escape: line 1 column 218748 (char 218747)
```

what is the problem?

Comment: The problem is that the request body has an invalid Unicode escape. If you told us what the characters around that position were (e.g., `request.body[218700:218800]`), or where the JSON came from, we might be able to tell you more, but with nothing but the error description, we can't tell you any more than is in the error description.

Comment: The most likely problem is that whatever's producing the JSON is not using a compliant JSON library, and isn't encoding astral characters (emoji, rare CJK last names, etc.) properly. But, even if that guess is right, that probably doesn't help you much more.

Comment: I cannot change server code to log what you want. But I have some machines which crawl data from some websites and send data by this command `requests.post(url, json=data, timeout=timeout, cookies=cookies, headers=headers)`

Comment: when server receives this data it raises the error. @abarnert

Comment: If you can't show us the JSON data, and can't tell us what URLs you're getting the JSON from, then there's really nothing anyone can do for you. If you've got code you can't change that can't deal with invalid JSON, and you feed it invalid JSON, you're going to get an error, and you just have to accept that.

Comment: So you write another sample little example similar to your code. I think the response contains some invalid metacharacters. Check https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_regexp_unicode_hex.asp.